Is there a general way to backup and restore UEFI/BIOS and NVRAM?
Executive Summary
My limited search on the web has found no general guidelines to backup and restore UEFI/BIOS and NVRAM. Each manufacturer has a way to write, e.g., update BIOS. Is there a way to read (backup) and write (restore), either from BIOS, or within an operating system? I did see some old discussions, such as this on SuperUser, but not much of use.
TL;DR
Specifically, yesterday, a PC that had been working well for some years refused to boot. Even after completely restoring a disk image, it rejected the OS. After attempts to repair booting, I finally resorted to:

Disabling Secure Boot, which had not been needed before,
Reinstalling Windows from ISO,
Reinstalling Linux,
Restoring the original disk image,
Finally, using shim-signed to allow Secure Boot to be re-enabled.

A bit of time (and aggravation) might have been avoided if I could have restored NVRAM to accept the existing boot loaders, instead. sigh

I'm not aware of a tool to back up / restore the whole NVRAM (also looking for same), but tools such as grub-install will update the NVRAM, and can restore missing entries that way. There are likely similar tools for Windows (boot repair?). Some UEFI settings UI may offer a native option to back up / restore settings.

@MichaelK, thanks for the idea of grub-install. It is explained well at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170347/what-does-no-nvram-do-while-installing-grub , and it might point me in the right direction.

The responses to reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/15leecw appear to discuss this, to some success.

@RokeJulianLockhart, Thanks -- that would have been useful, but is not compatible even with this Dell PC.

Per discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/68150/15, it might be that all current implementations of this technology are vendor-specific.
